# problem with wp theme uploading to server..?

Tags: themes, server-load

Please help me out.. I had uploaded new theme(child theme) in clients server.Theme folder has *twenty ten* and *child theme* now.But when i  activated the theme in admin side ,the twenty ten shows the corresponding child theme and the new  one shows the html template (from that html template i made the corresponding wordpress theme).Is this the problem with uploading? what went wrong ?

Comment: Still fuzzy. :) Could you please rephrase - what does `twenty ten shows` and `new one shows the html template` mean?

Comment: Can you give us the file listing of the `themes` directory? Perhaps your html template is in the way of something?

Comment: Actually client uploaded the wordpress in his server and asked me just upload the child theme i did .there were two themes 'ken' and 'twentyten' in theme folder.He told me to upload the theme in ken folder.i did it like that and change theme name in  style.css to ken.

Comment: hey am new to wp..plz forgive if am confusing u all..

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the list of files you now have in the `ken` directory? And the heading (first comment block) in the `style.css` of your `ken` theme?

Answer (score 1):

Codex has some [step by step instructions on manual theme upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Themes_SubPanel#Using_the_FTP_method).

In case of issues it is also worth checking if theme structure and meta information are adequate and [in line with technical requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

There is also [Theme Check](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/) plugin for automated testing, but it's unlikely to help if WP can't properly detect theme.